# How to simply run an applescript task from mac excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, macos, applescript

I am currently in the process of writing a VBA macro at work however I have run into a problem which I am hoping you can help me with.

All I am trying to do is simply run an applescript app from excel, this was very easy to do in the 2011 version but has seemingly gotten a lot more complicated in the 2016 edition.

I have researched various places online but with no luck, the only articles and guides I have come across point towards parameters and checking files but unfortunately I have no idea what any of those are. All I would like to do is to provide the filepath of the applescript  so that excel can run it, is these even possible anymore?

I have attached the relevant applescript file, please don't judge me too hard for how bad it is, I only started learning last week.

The code that worked in Excel 2011 was as follows:

```
OSA = "/usr/bin/osascript"
SCRIPT = "/users/savePDF.scpt"




MacScript ("do shell script " & Chr(34) & OSA & " " & SCRIPT & Chr(34))
```

However in excel 2016 I am trying to use the AppleScript task command but get a compile error that the argument is not optional. Although I am not sure what argument they are talking about

Many thanks for all your help.

Comment: How did you used to do it, how have you tried to do it so far, and what issues/errors are you facing when using these methods?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add any of that information, very daft of me. In Excel 2011 I managed to run the script using the following code:                                   OSA = "/usr/bin/osascript"
SCRIPT = "/users/savePDF.scpt"
  
  
MacScript ("do shell script " & Chr(34) & OSA & " " & SCRIPT & Chr(34))                In Excel 2016 I have tried using the "Applescripttask" command and get a compile error that the argument is not optional. Although I am unsure what the argument should include

Comment: Could see if following along carefully with this article gets things working: http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/applescripttask.htm

Comment: Hi Mikegrann thanks for the response, I have read that article and it gave me some insight but then muddied the waters more. In the article, he talks about event handlers and testing files, but I'm not really sure what all of that means, I just want to run a script.

Comment: just to clarify, I don't the applescript code to return a boolean value which then influences by VBA code. I simply just basically want to open the application, akin to double clicking on it, perhaps there is another way to do this without using the applescript command?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like such a stupid question now I've finally figured out the answer.

Seeing as I didn't to control any variables or pass any values back and forth between applescript and VBA, the applescripttask command was pretty useless for me.

I ended up being able to launch the ".app" by simple using the hyperlink command, as follows:

```
   ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="/Users/(usernamehere)/Desktop/savePDF1.app", NewWindow:=True
```