# How is AppleScriptTask called from Excel 365 VBA on Mac mini running Big Sur?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run an AppleScript from VBA in an Excel 365 macro.

I get:

> Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument

I have this script called "PythonCommand.scpt" in my /Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Excel folder:

```
on PythonCommandHandler(pythonScript)
    --do shell script "/usr/local/bin/Python3" & pythonScript
    return "Handler ended!  " & pythonScript
end PythonCommandHandler
```

I commented out the "do" statement so I should simply get back what I send it. I tested this in the script editor by adding a line to invoke the function and it works.

I have this code in my VBA macro:

```vb
Dim result      As String
Dim strPyScript As String
strPyScript = "xxxx"
result = AppleScriptTask("/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Excel/PythonCommand.scpt", "PythonCommandHandler", strPyScript)
```

When I run it I get the error '5'.

I changed the first argument to "PythonCommand.scpt" instead of the whole path but got the same error.
I put the last argument in as a quoted string instead of using a variable and got the same result.

I looked at this post:
[How can I launch an external python process from Excel 365 VBA on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319389/how-can-i-launch-an-external-python-process-from-excel-365-vba-on-osx)
and started my coding from there (this example had the first argument with no path).
Then I read this one:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/office-mac/applescripttask from Microsoft which is specific to using the AppleScriptTask command. It lays out the process a bit more clearly but is basically the same.

I looked at this post:
[How to simply run an applescript task from mac excel 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723420/how-to-simply-run-an-applescript-task-from-mac-excel-2016) which has a broken link to a Ron deBruin article which I found here:
https://macexcel.com/examples/setupinfo/applescripttask/index.html
which is quite clear and easier to read but says basically the same thing.
The post with the broken link was resolved by making the script an app and invoking it as a hyperlink. I tried that and it works but there are several shortcomings with that approach: can't pass an argument to the script, can't get anything back from the script, and control does not wait for the script to end before executing the next line of VBA code.

I turned on all the references I could find in Tools References but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Phil,

The code I use is:

```
res = AppleScriptTask("selectFile.scpt", "GetFile", args)
```

NB I don't need to put the full path to the scpt file.  I presume this is because it is sandboxed and so vba knows where it is.

BTW I put the scpt file in this folder:
${HOME}/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Excel

The folder you have specified is not a user folder, but rather a system folder.

Comment: Sorry I should have said I am using Excel365 on a Macbook Pro running Big Sur.  The scpt folder I am using is probably specific to Excel365.

Comment: Thank you for responding VaughanR!  By ${HOME} I assume you mean my "Macintosh HD/Users/minime" folder.  I looked there, found a "Containers" folder but no com.microsoft.Excel folder so I tried to create it and got a message that the name already exists.  I can see other hidden folders and files, any idea why I can't see this one?  If I can't see it I can't drill down to the sub folders to move the script there.

Comment: I did some research and then used the Option key and Go then typed in com.microsoft.Excel and it worked so I was able to drill down to the folder you mentioned and my scripts are already there!  Is it possible this folder is obtainable via an alias or something?  Maybe one of the other attempts I made above resulted in the scripts being here.  Anyway I tried again and got the same result: Error 5.  but it took longer to get it than usual.  I'm going to look into this more.  It is encouraging to hear that someone actually has this working!

Comment: It Worked!!  The delay was caused by a mistake I had in the script (the name of the handler didn't match the name in the AppleScriptTask command).  So it looks like I can get this error for either a problem in the VBA command or a problem in the script itself.  Either way you helped me get this working!  Thank you!

Comment: VaughanR, I have noticed on my mini that that one of the folders in the path you stated in your comment appears to have an alias that can be confusing: where you have"...Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/..." the "com.microsoft.Excel" is called "Microsoft Excel".  When I typed com... into the Go command it actually changes to this name.  The folder named "Microsoft Excel" does show in my path.  Very strange.  I can live with this.  Something else is happening that I can't explain except to assume I have actually gone mad!

Comment: I tried to change the script and my change didn't work.  My assumption was that the one being executed wasn't the one I thought it was so I looked for all the instances of my script with that name.  I have two but as I tried to change each one I got more confused.  The original unchanged version is the only one being executed.  I ate lunch and tried again methodically.  I opened a Finder window to each instance and opened each.  They only had one set of my changes.  I looked again and they both now look like the original version!  I just looked again and they both have a change I made earlier.

Comment: I know this sounds absurd but I swear it's true.  Is my system possessed or is there some explanation for all this?  In spite of all the changes only the original version of the script is being executed, regardless of what I see in the script editor.  By the way, if I change the name of either instance the name of the other instance changes and the VBA command fails.  This confirms my initial thought that one of these libraries must be an alias of the other and seems to confirm that this is what is being executed.  But what is going on with the content of the script?

Comment: Phil, it was awhile ago I did this (last year), but I believe I edited the script in a local folder and then when I had it running the way I wanted, I copied it into the sandbox.  You are right the longer path is an alias to ~/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Excel/.  I would suggest you might not be editing the version of the script that ends up being run. I do remember I had a bit of difficulty with that at first.

Comment: The difficulty with versions of the script was something odd about the way the Apple script editor works as I recall.

Comment: Thanks VaughanR.  I really appreciate your help with this.  Yes I agree, I too found the best procedure is to work in another library and move the finished script to either of the folders.   I can now, thanks to your help, get an AppleScriptTask to perform correctly and consistently!  Thank you. Now if I can just get that script to call a Python script I'll be all set!

Comment: @Phil, I'm having a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76367624/invalid-procedure-call-or-argument-when-calling-applescripttask-from-vba-excel-i). In the end what is the folder where the scpt must be?

Answer (score 0):

I have the script I called "PythonCommand.scpt" in this folder:
Macintosh HD>Users>minime>Library>Application Scripts>Com Microsoft.Excel

"minime" is my username on my Mac mini.
I hope this helps.  It took me quite a while but once I finally got this working I never looked back.  I use this script to execute all my Python scripts from Excel 365 on my Mac.

You may find it helpful to do a search for the com.microsoft library or one of the other nodes in the path.  I had a lot of trouble trying to see all the libraries.
Best of Luck!
Phil