# Invalid procedure call or argument when calling AppleScriptTask from VBA Excel in macOS

Tags: excel, vba, macos, applescript

This is the piece of the VBA code that I run before saving the workbook.

```
Dim lastValue As String
lastValue = ws.Range("A" & firstEmptyRow - 1).Value
Dim result As String
result = AppleScriptTask("SaveLastNLTextFile.scpt", "SaveTextToFile", lastValue)
```

This last value is the last id which I want to keep in a text file.
The AppleScript (SaveLastNLTextFile.scpt) is in /Users/myuser/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Excel/SaveLastNLTextFile.scpt and has the following code:

```
on SaveTextToFile(textToSave)
    set filePath to "/Users/myuser/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive/My Drive/_LastNL.txt"
    set fileReference to open for access filePath with write permission
    set eof of fileReference to 0
    write textToSave to fileReference starting at eof
    close access fileReference
    return textToSave
end SaveTextToFile
```

The strange thing is that this is working perfectly, i.e. it is saving correctly the lastValue, but VBA is throwing an error "5 - Invalid procedure call or argument" in the line where I'm calling AppleScriptTask, and I don't have any idea on what might be the issue. I already restarted the computer and gave writing permissions to the applescript.

I'm on macOS Ventura 13.4 (M1).

Comment: You should (always) include the version of excel. Microsoft has made changes — I think specifically — around applescripttask. Also, if you are using a `scpt` file, then it is a document and not an application so giving it permissions isn't valid. Provide your OS version so people can advise how best to ensure the correct permissions. Finally, and I'm guessing here because I'm not familiar with mixing and matching vba and applescript, your vba script offers 3 parameters to the handler but the handler only takes 1. Perhaps the error is related to that.

Comment: I'm using only 1 parameter, as I was following directly Microsoft page instructions [Run an AppleScript with VB](url)https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/office-mac/applescripttask

Comment: I see your point. BTW, what version of excel? Also thinking that using `result` as a variable might be an issue as it is a reserved word in applescript but I'm not sure that the script ever has to deal with it. What happens if you change the code in the `SaveTextToFile` handler to something really trivial (i.e. not editing the file). Per [Invalid procedure call or argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/invalid-procedure-call-or-argument-error-5), it is either the argument is out of range (unlikely) or procedure is invalid on OS.

Comment: I changed `result`to `output`but the problem continued. Then I tested line by line and the error appears in `close access fileReference`. If I don't have it, I get no error. I don't if that's necessary for other reasons, but i just left it commented for now.

Comment: Access should always be closed but [apple advises](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW29): `Any files left open will be automatically closed when the application exits.` If that is extent of script then it shouldn't cause any issues. It might be a problem if you tried opening a file's access again within the handler. FWIW, the applescript code works without error for me. If you look in Window > Log History, do you see something like this: `close access 62`?

Comment: Window > Log History is empty for me (Result, Messages, Events and Replies). When I run the script from VBA not even Events are filled. Only when I run the `scpt`file from within script editor events appear (Events + Time), but again, everything else is empty (The right side: Result, Messages, Events and Replies).

Comment: Alas, I'm not sure how to reproduce that. All I'm doing is making a script with two lines (set the var to a random string, call the handler with that var as the parameter) along with the handler. Then I run it in script editor.